# Each() div with two classes and add css if this div has children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I do not understand where I'm wrong ....

```
<div class="gsc-webResult gsc-result">Ciao</div>
<div class="gsc-webResult gsc-result">
    <td class="gsc-table-cell-thumbnail gsc-thumbnail">Ciao2</td>
</div>


$(".gsc-webResult .gsc-result").each(function () {
   if ($(this).children('td').not('.gsc-table-cell-thumbnail gsc-thumbnail')) {

     $(this).css('margin-left', '60px');
   }
 });
```

I want to add the '`margin-left`' to div that has tag `td` with those classes (`.gsc-table-cell-thumbnail gsc-thumbnail`) as a children

link jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/s0b75ekw/

thanks

Comment: y are you using td inside div instead of using in a Table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quiet messed up code

```
<div class="gsc-webResult gsc-result">Ciao</div>
<div class="gsc-webResult gsc-result">
    <span class="gsc-table-cell-thumbnail gsc-thumbnail">Ciao2</span>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(".gsc-webResult.gsc-result").each(function () {
//               ^ Remove the space from here Otherwise it will be nested classes 

   // Calculate the number of child this element has with tag td and specified classes.
   if ($(this).find('span.gsc-table-cell-thumbnail.gsc-thumbnail').length>0)    
   {
     $(this).css('margin-left', '60px');
   }
});
```

Comment: Didn't work besause `td` cannot be nested inside `div` elements. Change the `td` to a `div` or `span` and it works. Link jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s0b75ekw/1/

Comment: @LucasVicente : Yeah thanks a lot.. You need to change `td` to `div` or `span`, didnt notice that.